# run my script after chosen.jquery has completed execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the color of the Li tags based on the value they contain, which is true or false. The problem is that I am using chosen.jquery.min.js to do some UI manipulation. You can find an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Imirhoxha/s6kv8a2m/16/) of my code.

Because chosen.jquery is creating a copy of the list and inserting them as LIs into UL element, my code executes before the Li elements are inserted in the UL element. How can I run my code after the chosen.jquery library has finished its execution of code and manipulated the dom?

```js
var sectors = $("#userProfileSectors > option");

var userProfChosen = $("#userProfileSectors_chosen");
var cities = userProfChosen.find(".chosen-drop").find(".chosen-results");
cities.css("background-color", "silver");

sectors.each(function() {
  var sectorText = $(this).text();
  var sectorVal = $(this).val();

  cities.find("li").each(function() {
    if (sectorText === $(this).text()) {

      $(this).attr("data-web-exists", sectorVal);

      if ($(this).attr("data-web-exists") == "False") {

        $(this).css("background-color", "red")
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="SelectedCities" id="userProfileSectors" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; " multiple="multiple">
  <option value="True">Brussels</option>
  <option value="False">Antwerpen</option>
  <option value="False">Gent</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="True">Berlin</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="True">Tirana</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="False">London</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the flow of your application. I think you need to update your example a bit more. where are the dynamic elements coming from and where are they going to? Right now I just see a list of cities with no real function

Comment: If you want to simply highlight the option that is already chosen, just use CSS: `.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Vanilla JavaScript**

You can check that the DOM is ready, via [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) property.

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  //Already loaded!
}
```

**2. jQuery**

or you check via jQuery method [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for Chosen if is ready to build the DOM, like this:

```
$("#userProfileSectors").on("chosen:ready", function(){
    alert("I am ready!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following, as whenever the value is chosen chosen.jquery executes the change function as shown in document [chosen document](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events)
so you can add your logic to change the color in this function.
your function will look something like this check it is extension of your fiddle

```js
$("#userProfileSectors").chosen({ width: "100%" }).change(function(){
alert('some function to be executed after you choose the element');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select name="SelectedCities" id="userProfileSectors" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; " multiple="multiple"><option value="True">Brussels</option>
<option value="False">Antwerpen</option>
<option value="False">Gent</option>
<option selected="selected" value="True">Berlin</option>
<option selected="selected" value="True">Tirana</option>
<option selected="selected" value="False">London</option>
</select>
```